# how to find maximum of a group of rows in a certain column which satisfies a condition in tibco spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I want to find maximum of a group of rows in a certain column which satisfies a condition in TIBCO Spotfire. For example, consider the table below:

```
col 1|col 2|col 3
  1  |  2  |  y  
  1  |  3  |  y  
  1  |  6  |  y  
  1  |  8  |  n  
  1  |  7  |  n  
  1  |  6  |  y  
  2  |  2  |  y  
  2  |  10 |  y  
  2  |  6  |  y  
  2  |  9  |  n  
  2  |  7  |  y  
  2  |  6  |  n
```

I want to group all the rows with `[col 1] = 1`, and find the max of col 2 considering only those rows that have `[col 3] = "y"`.

My final table must look like:

```
col 1|col 2|col 3|col 4
  1  |  2  |  y  | 6
  1  |  3  |  y  | 6
  1  |  6  |  y  | 6
  1  |  8  |  n  | 6
  1  |  7  |  n  | 6
  1  |  6  |  y  | 6
  2  |  2  |  y  | 10
  2  |  10 |  y  | 10
  2  |  6  |  y  | 10
  2  |  9  |  n  | 10
  2  |  7  |  y  | 10
  2  |  6  |  n  | 10
```

Can some one please help me out with this?

Comment: i have created one column which finds the maximum, and then with that the actual column which i need, but i wanted to do without using that extra column, because i'm using this logic many times, so i ended up creating 40+ calculated columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First(case  when [col 3]="y" then Max([col 2]) OVER ([col 1]) end) OVER ([col 1]) should do the trick (version 7.5).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with something that sounds like what you already tried, but here goes.

1. Insert Calculated Column: CASE  WHEN [col 3]="y" THEN Max([col 2]) OVER ([col 1]) END AS [calc]
2. Insert Calculated Column: Max([calc]) OVER ([col 1]) AS [col 4]

Those give me the value in [col 4] that you were looking for.

[image: Calculated Column Results]

Comment: Yes this is what i have done, but i ended up having too many calculated columns since i want to use this logic multiple times. Any way thanks for the help, I'm still trying to fig out a way, If i do i will share.

Answer (score -1):

@monte_fisto in the similar case can we identify the min and max of a col2